# How to add result of a mongo find query into another find query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

First of all I am searching for all group documents in my collection:

```
const groups = await Content.find({ type: 'group' }).toArray()
```

For this array I need to find each children documents and add them to the object:

```
groups.map(async g => {
  g.content = await Content.find({
    type: 'element',
    parent: g._id
  }).toArray()

  console.log(g) // <-- has content field, which is what I am expecting
})

console.log(groups) // <-- content field is missing
```

---

*Example*

To make it a bit more clearer: `groups` could have this result:

```
[{
  _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i',
  title: 'Title',
  type: 'group',
}]
```

Now I'm searching for each element (in this example it has only one) for all documents with the parent ID and this result should be added as a field to `group`.

```
[{
  _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i',
  title: 'Title',
  type: 'group',
  content: [
    { _id: '1', title: 'example', parent: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i' },
    { _id: '2', title: 'another example', parent: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i' }
  ]
}]
```

In my attempt I do not get the content when doing console.log outside the map().

And maybe it is possible to do this directly with my mongoDB query (I'm using [mongoDB native driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect case where you are looking for `Promise.all`

```
var promiseArray = groups.map(g => {
  return Content.find({type: 'element',parent: g._id},function(err,cursor){
       g['content'] = cursor.toArray();
       return g;
  });
})

Promise.all(promiseArray ).then(function(groups) {
    console.log(groups)
})
```

Comment: But still I do not get the correct output for `console.log(groups)`. There is still my content field missing. I think it is a problem because it is async...

Comment: @user3142695 give it a try now